# Edits to counter created with Travery css/html and jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I've followed a Youtube tutorial to create this counter for a client. It works great but it needs to add a few elements. I want to add a prefix ($), suffix (%) and also commas.
$100,000 or 80% for example.

Thoughts?

```
counters.forEach(counter => {
    const updateCount = () => {
        const target = +counter.getAttribute('data-target');
        const count = +counter.innerText;

        // Lower inc to slow and higher to slow
        const inc = target / speed;

        // console.log(inc);
        // console.log(count);

        // Check if target is reached
        if (count < target) {
            // Add inc to count and output in counter
            counter.innerText = Math.ceil(count + inc);
            // Call function every ms
            setTimeout(updateCount, 1);
        } else {
            counter.innerText = target;
        }
        if (count >1000){
            $("span.numbers").digits();
    };

    updateCount();
});
```

```
<section class="counters">
     <div>
          <div class="counter" data-target="100000">0</div>
          <h3>Currency </h3>
          <h4>Title</h4>
     </div>
    
     <div>
          <div class="counter" data-target="80">0</div>
          <h3>percentage </h3>
          <h4>Title</h4>
     </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.Your code is js only but you tagged jquery. Anyway use css `::before` to this work. See https://jsfiddle.net/qdvnf9tc/

Comment: While you can probably use before (and after) pseudo elements in CSS  as @Mohammad suggests to add the $ and % signs to the elements you can't do that for the comma in the middle of a number. You probably need to put the counts as globals, not rely on innerHTML. Could you put up a working snippet.

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad - that worked great. @A Haworth , makes sense... I'm new to this so all i have to go on is the tutorial i made this with. I'll see what i come up w.